# Метод equals в классе Object и в моем

Tags: java

Вот метод `equals()` в классе `Object`:

```
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

Если `this` (объект) равен аргументу в методе `equals` (объекту), то возвращает `true` либо уже `false`.

А вот equals переопределенный в моём классе.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Cat cat = (Cat) o;
        return id == cat.id;
    }
```

Но тут получается тоже самое:

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
```

Только есть в отличие от первого примера оператор `if`, но отрабатывает так же получается если объект равен аргументу (объекту) возвращает `true`, правильно ли я понял? Помогите разобраться

Comment: в 1ом и 3ем примере вы сравниваете ссылки на объекты(адреса в памяти)

Answer (score 1):

Знак `==` который используется в классе `Object` проверяет равенство **ссылок**, а не самих объектов. Равенство ссылок гаранитирует, что они ссылаются на один и тот же объект, а значит и сам объект один и тот же, он точно равен сам себе.

Поэтому, когда переопределяется метод `equals`, зачастую сразу сравнивают ссылки, это относительно быстрая и 'дешевая' проверка. Если же ссылки отличаются, идут проверки по классам, полям и т.д.

То есть, мы делаем самую дешевую операцию, а если её результат вернул `false`, копаем глубже, и сравниваем основательно.